Use %~nx1 in Breakout to File
I am trying to create a log file that only uses the file name and extension, I am able to get this in addition to the full path using %1, but using %~nx1 causes a crash. I even tried setting my own variable using %~nx1 earlier on, then using my custom variable in place but the same problem occurs. How can I breakout the information I need?
set "InFile=%~nx1"
(
echo Infile: %InFile%
)>> "file.log"


Can you inform the specific input name that is causing the crash? For me it works perfectly as should except that when the input file is in another folder than the batch the file.log is saved in same folder as where the actual input file is.

@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0"
set "_InFile=%~nx1"

>>".\file.log" =;(
     set /p "'=Infile: %_InFile%"
    );= <nul 


Please understand that there is no accurate information:
1. Regarding the error(s), there is no screenshot of the error(s) or text with any descriptive details;
2. No information about the layout of the file name used in the argument, (whether or not it contains characters such as &, !, (, ), ", ', etc..);
3. Information if the batch is invoked/executed via the command line directly within the folder where it is located, or if clicked via explorer;
4. Not even in code do you have any batch path and/or file path passed in argument 1
5. Nor if your working folder is the same as the origin of this file in argument or if the final file file.log to be fed is in the same folder as the running batch.

@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0"
set "_InFile=%~nx1"

>>".\file.log" =;(
     echo/Infile:
     set /p "'=%_InFile%"
    );= <nul 


This produces the desired result, however; It prints the information on the same line. Is there a way to print to a new line?

In my tests if the filename has parentheses on them like "Hello how are (you).txt" I get a crash cause you used parentheses for the echo part which doesn't really seem necessary to me and you can just remove them. The following code works having the input file parentheses or not:
set "InFile=%~nx1"
>>"file.log" echo Infile: %InFile%


The parenthesis are needed, the echo is between them as one of several actions, all of which are broken out into the log file. Example of multi-line or multi command capture to a log:
(
echo Line 1
echo Line 2
...
)>>file.log
